# jQuery get tag in tag with selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="test">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I want to add an li to the bottom of the first ul.

I'm sure I have seen somewhere something like `$("test:nav:ul")`,
but I cant find any help about something similar,
could you guys please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#test ul:first').append('<li>anything inside li</li>');
```

or if performance matters, use:

```
$('#test ul').filter(':first').append('<li>something here</li>');
```

or you can also use:

```
$('#test ul').first().append('<li>something here</li');
```

even you can go backwards:

```
$('<li>something</li>').appendTo('#test ul:first');
```

Comment: **$('#test ul:first').append('<li>hello</li>');**

Comment: Because `:first` pseudo-class is a jQuery extension. You can't see `:first` in CSS Specification. Thus, jQuery can't use `querySelectorAll()` method (which is implemented by browsers).

Comment: `.eq(0)` is faster than `filter(':first')`

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the descendant selector: `$('#test nav ul:first')`

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#test ul:first").append("<li></li>");
```

[`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)  selects the first matched element, in this case the first `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#test nav ul:first").append('<li>Three</li>');
```

If you are using IE <= 8, then use this:

```
$("#test ul:first").append('<li>Three</li>');
```

The `#` means `ID=`.  The spaces between the terms mean "descendant".  And `:first` gets the 1st element from the set (`UL` in this case).  Since the ULs are a descendant of `#test` the selector, `nav` isn't really needed.

Comment: just a notice, this dosent work. i think 'nav' is not recognized.

Comment: Dosent work on IE8, even the jsfiddler example. it works only if you remove 'nav'

Answer (score 0):

You could get it with something like this,

```
$('ul').first()
```

o just add an id to the ul and get it by id with

```
$('#id')
```